# Align two views in opposites sides (one at the top and one at the bottom) and be able to push the bottom view when the top view grows?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview, nestedrecyclerview

I basically have an EditText aligned at the top of the view and there's a RecyclerView on the bottom of the view that can also grow (with the newest item on the bottom)
That's easily doable with a constraint layout but my problem is that when the EditText grows it should start pushing down the list. But the list was initially aligned at the bottom of the parent. (and everything should be scrollable)
I hope this image makes things more clear

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to avoid forming a vertical chain (so that the EditText at the top always stays in place) and also to leverage the `app:layout_constrainedHeight` attribute on the RecyclerView in order to make it shrink when the EditText grows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The combination of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`, along with both top and bottom constraints, means that the RecyclerView will always be only as tall as its items *or* the available space below the EditText, whichever is smaller.

The `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` attribute ensures that, when the list doesn't fill the screen, it sits at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to the previous answer and if you want to be able to scroll your layout you can use sth like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This will make everything align as you want to and you are able to scroll down to see your full `recyclerView`. `NestedScrollView` will make sure that everything runs smoothly.